# Clarification needed: SP List Graph api webhook notifications

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, microsoft-graph-webhooks

I've created a Graph subscription for changes (`ChangeType = "updated"`) in a Sharepoint List according to docs; and am also receiving notifications with no issues. But... why does the `resourceData` of the notification contain just one property?

```
[...]
"resourceData": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.ListItem"
},
[...]
```

I would expect something more like this:

```
"resourceData": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.ListItem",
    "AdditionalData": {
        "Id": "1234"
    }
},
```

Minor config info: the app creating the subscription & receiving the notification has the `Sites.ReadWrite.All` application permission.

As for the clarification: are my expectations just too high and I misunderstood the notification definition/function, or is there some way how to get the itemId from the notification body?

Thx